# Send variables from one class to routes.js (without props)

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, core-ui

I'm trying to make a React route path dynamic and for this I need to send a variable `clickedSubprojectName` to my routes.js.

right now my `routes.js` looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const Projects = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Projects'));
const Subproject= React.lazy(() => import('./views/Subproject'));

const routes = [
  { path: '/projects', exact: true, name: 'Projects', component: Projects },
  { path: "/projects/subprojects", name: 'Subproject', component: Subproject},

];

export default routes;
```

In my `Projects.js` I created a `state variable` which saves the name of the subproject where the user clicked on. And I want to pass this variable from my Projects class to my routes.js so that I can set the path in routes for example like this:

`{ path: "/projects/"+clickedSubprojectName, name: 'Subproject', component: Subproject}`

I've already tried to export a constant variable from my `Projects.js` like this:

```
    export const clickedSubprojectName={
      clickedSubprojectName: this.state.clickedSubprojectName}
```

and then imported `import { clickedSubprojectName} from './views/Subproject'` in my routes.js
but this isn't really working. This sets the clickedSubprojectName as the default of the state variable at the first time when the Projects component gets rendered and it doesn't get updated when the state variable changes.

Hope anyone have a solution for this problem because I haven't found anything on stackoverflow yet

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for dynamic routes.. you can use something like..

```
{ path: "/projects/:subproject", name: 'Subproject', component: Subproject},
```

and you can invoke this route by `history.push("/projects" + this.state.clickedSubprojectName)`

```
export const clickedSubprojectName={
      clickedSubprojectName: this.state.clickedSubprojectName}
```

this definitely won't work.. this variable gets exported once and imported once. So it will always return the default value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked :-) 
what does "/:subproject" in path stand for?

and is there a way to set the name in`{ path: "/projects/:subproject", *name*: 'Subproject', component: Subproject}` also dynamic depending on which subproject were called?

Comment: glad.. it worked.. `/:subproject` is an example of nested route which can accept dynamic values as its pathname. if you are using hooks, you can also get the value of `subproject` inside the component using `useParams()` hook.

Comment: I am not sure.. why would you use a name property in a route. but i can make it work, if i had the full code. Also please don't forget to upvote and accept my answer, if it helped.